# A few Javascript/CSS animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, testing

[Here is my code (Plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/kdwH6LFcp4R5FgfMIlCS?p=preview)

I'm having trouble with making the position fixed after the "Pack" image enlarges, as well, I would like it to fade in larger and fade out smaller both with 1 second intervals.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    var pack_image = document.getElementById('pack');
    if(pack_image && pack_image.style) {
        pack_image.style.top = '50%';
        pack_image.style.left = '50%';
        pack_image.style.height = '350px';
        pack_image.style.width = '250px';
    }
},7000);
```

I tried keeping the position with `top = %50` and `left = %50` but it's not working. I have no idea how to add the fade in and out effects for it though, please help. I'm new to JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use keyframes in css.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

You can use css  classes for an animation and add this class via jquery to an existing class or I'd from your HTML.

Comment: I'm not too sure how I can use them for this.. Thanks for helping though. :)